# recvfrom() not receiving any data - python 3.6

Tags: sockets, python-3.6

In python 2.7 and 3.6 we are getting socket object as :

```
  <socket._socketobject object at 0x0000000008C5FA08>
```

and in python 3.6 we are getting socket object as:

```
 <socket.socket fd=1616, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM, proto=0, laddr=('169.254.126.94', 6970)>
```

With python 2.7 our code is working perfectly fine but with python 3.6 its not working and it's seems to get stuck on the recvfrom() call.

The program simply runs forever in recvfrom() call.

Here is the code:

```
def receive_socket(self, receive_socket, server_address):
    receive_server_addr = receive_socket.getsockname()
    while True:
        try:
            print("Started--------------")
            data, server = receive_socket.recvfrom(65565)
            print("Receiving data-------------", data)
```

Note: This code works perfectly in python 2.7.

Comment: Is there some guarantee that the `recvfrom` call will never block? How does this handle the case when there is no data available?

Comment: @bnaecker Using receive_sock.settimeout(5.0) when there is no data available... Also am getting this error  :  my_socket.bind((connection_addr, 0))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context.. Sorry i didn't mention in the question.

Comment: That error is raised when trying to bind to an IP address not assigned to the an interface on the machine. Are you sure `connection_addr` is valid for the machine you're on?

Comment: @bnaecker Yes it gives ip "169.254.11.49".